# In Opera the border on input button disappears when the text field becomes active, how can i prevent that?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, opera

I'm trying to style the submit button on the wordpress search widget, but Opera is giving me trouble.

I've set a 1px solid border on the button, and it appears fine until the text input is activated, then the border on the button seems to disappear (or becomes black, i can't tell).

This does not happen in firefox where the button appears the same even if the text field is activated.

This is the css i have now:

```
li.widget_search #searchform #searchsubmit
{
    height: 24px !important;
    border-color: #ff9900;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #201300;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #FFB100;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li.widget_search #searchform #searchsubmit:active
{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an Opera issue. It always adds a black border if a border is specified on button focus, regardless of the settings of that border (color or style at least). All other browsers display a nice blue border here, inheriting all the settings from the normal button CSS rule.

You can prevent this on your own button by removing the border from the button:focus style.

Try...

```
a.button:active { border:0px; }
```

Comment: Setting "border-style: none;" to the #mybutton:focus doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you any code we could see? Not ideal but maybe you could use javascript to change the style when the input field is active?

Comment: "border:0px;" on #mybutton:active doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Liam, i've added the css i have at the moment. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try... #searchsubmit:active {border:1px solid #ff9900;}

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. Even when i set border width to 50px just to see if it has any effect nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
I think Mr. David Murdoch's advice is the best for Opera ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126445/any-way-to-remove-ies-black-border-around-submit-button-in-active-forms/3365781#3365781) ). I've tried his approach in Opera and I succeeded basically doubling the input tags in this way:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" style="display:none;" id="WorkaroundForOperaInputFocusBorderBug" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

This way the 1st element is hidden but it CATCHES the display focus Opera would give to the 2nd input element instead. LOVE IT!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `button` element instead of an `input`, e.g.

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

and you won't see the black border in Opera.