# Black box around input button in OPERA?

Tags: php, html, css, opera

1. List item

Why is a black box appear around input button in opera.
Here is the jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/PKRRj/

try clicking on the button

TRY in OPERA. No problem with the other browsers.

Additional Information regarding Browser.

About Opera 
Version information
Version
11.50

Build
1074

Platform
Win32

System
Windows 7

- What i did

Clicked once on the button
[image]

Comment: What version of Opera? What OS?

Comment: Opera, windows 7, identifiys itself as: "Version 11.50 Build 1074", no black rim. What's that thing in the corner? a pluging? or some other plugin around that puts a black ring on a focussed object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Opera the border on input button disappears when the text field becomes active, how can i prevent that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213609/in-opera-the-border-on-input-button-disappears-when-the-text-field-becomes-active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a bug in Opera. I could not find a way to completely remove it but here is a sort of work around.

Remove any border from the input element on focus:

```
.buttonStyle1 {
    ...
}
.buttonStyle1:focus {
    border:none;
}
```

I know it's not the way way to fix this especially if you need a border. Hopefully Opera will fix this.

Comment: yeah.. so the bug is with border in opera.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in Opera 11.50b1074 on Windows 7.

[image: Opera screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think Mr. David Murdoch's advice is the best for Opera ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126445/any-way-to-remove-ies-black-border-around-submit-button-in-active-forms/3365781#3365781) ).

I've tried his approach in Opera and I succeeded basically doubling the input tags in this way:

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" style="display:none;" id="WorkaroundForOperaInputFocusBorderBug" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

This way the 1st element is hidden but it CATCHES the display focus Opera would give to the 2nd input element instead. LOVE IT!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that in the current Opera and Firefox under Linux, no black box at all. Maybe you should provide more informations like Opera Version and Operating System?

Comment: or a link to the page, it may be other code than the small sample you posted.

Comment: @dagon. if it was, then i wudn't see it in the jsfiddle sample.

Comment: your the only one that sees it at all.

Comment: sure its not just a jsfiddle. issue?

Comment: @dagon. try clicking on it once.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `button` element instead of an `input`:
http://jsfiddle.net/PKRRj/65/

and you won't see the black border in Opera.