# how to remove black border around button in IE7 when apply opacity

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to remove IEs black border around submit button in active forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126445/any-way-to-remove-ies-black-border-around-submit-button-in-active-forms)

I can see black border around button in IE7 on windows XP. Here is the css.

```
.disabled {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[image]

I don't see any issue elsewhere except Windows XP IE7

Comment: @Eric I already tried this. unfortunately doesn't work here. There is no issue  when I remove opacity  :(

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that it's because the button is disabled. IE has some ugly disabled styles that you can't really work around. My next suggestion would be try to throw a `border:0` on there and see what happens.