# IE Showing black border outline on submit button

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to understand why IE 7>10 is showing a black border on a submit button. In order to clear it, I have to click inside the fieldset and then it goes away. But comes back when I click send or cancel. Is this a common problem with IE? I have included screenshot. Thanks!

[image: IE Black border error pic]

css code

```
.submit
        {

        margin:-50px 0 0 -148px;
        background-color:#eee;
        height:40px;
        width:120px;
        padding:0;
        border:1px solid #666;
        color:#42A0FF;

        }

.cancel
        {

        margin: -51px 0 0 -20px;
        background-color:#eee;
        height:40px;
        width:120px;
        padding:0;
        border:1px solid #666;
        color:#42A0FF;

        }

fieldset
        {

        background:#f2f2e6;
        border-color:#cccccc #cccccc #cccccc #cccccc;
        margin:10px 0 46px -150px;
        width:404px;
        display:block;
        text-height:10px;
        padding-bottom:15px;
        }
```

Comment: Your html please? without that who can help?

Comment: It's probably just browser-default styling (all browsers have it). Have you tried a `border: none;` CSS rule on the button/element with the border?

Comment: This *might* be an accessibility feature of IE to indicate which button will count as being *pressed* when the user submits the form via enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the main input

```
 input {border:0; margin:0;padding:0;}
```

And add a span to give the span the border you want so it will work universally:

```
.input-shell {border: #ccc 1px solid}
```

`<span class="input-shell"><input button /></span>`....

Heres a JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/tqnhg/1/

Heres a ref of same thing:

[Any way to remove IEs black border around submit button in active forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126445/any-way-to-remove-ies-black-border-around-submit-button-in-active-forms)

Finally do this:

```
  input[type=submit],
    input[type=reset],
    input[type=button]
    {
        filter:chroma(color=#000000);
        color:#cccccc;
    }
```