# No shadow, no outline, no border on active button

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove all shadow, border or other outline elements of an active border in the Ionic Framework.

So far, I tried to modify the .sass file using the following metrics:

**to remove the border**

```
$light:                           rgba(255,255,255,0.0) !default;
$button-positive-bg:              $positive !default;
$button-positive-text:            $positive-text !default;
$button-positive-border:          $light !default;!default;
$button-positive-active-bg:       $light !default;!default;
$button-positive-active-border:   $light !default;!default;
```

**to remove the shadow and other**

```
.button:active{
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

However, I still see a small shadow when the button is pressed (grey on white background, darkened on coloured background). How can I remove all these active elements? I just want a plain button.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get shadows on buttons in my app. Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: When you inspect the button, does the `box-shadow:` have a strikethrough? like something is overriding it?  One way to make `!important` even more important is by adding more parent classes to the element.  If you are using .button everywhere, maybe they all have a similar  parent class.  try `body .button:active{...}`

Comment: Here is an workaround, might help you!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126445/any-way-to-remove-ies-black-border-around-submit-button-in-active-forms

Comment: @isherwood: I am using Ionic

Comment: @ntgCleaner how can you check? I tried with .body, but still it shows up.

Comment: @JohnAndrews, Take a look at your button in something like chrome or safari, right click on it and look at the styles (usually on the right side).  Also don't use `.body` because that means it's looking for an element with the class name `body`.  Instead, remove the dot (`.`) and just write `body .button:active {...}`

Comment: Thanks, tried the body but didnt work. When inspecting the element, I noticed that it adds an css "activated" behind the css classes, so like: <button class="button button-light HERE">...

Comment: solved it! but changing the css class .activated

Comment: @humble.rumble thanks for the tip, coming soon, it is late here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @ntgCleaner, who showed how to use the Chrome debugger (see comments on my post), I found out that when clicking on the button, you will see how the class changes from

```
class="button"
```

to

```
class = "button activated"
```

So in my css/sass file, I added:

```
.button.activated {

 // my custom styiling

}
```

and that worked!